# html form does not respond to hitting "enter" button

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have this `html` form, which does not actually sends data to a php file, buts sends data to a javascipt function.

Works fine if I hit the "Go" button, but if I choose something and hit "enter", does not work. Does not send the data to the function, that is.

I have made other forms with the same pattern, to send data to a javascript function in the same file and they work . This one refuses.

How do I fix this? Thanks

```
<form id="boroughform" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="#" onSubmit="return goborough(this); return false;" >
Choose borough:<br/>
 <select name="boroughselect" id="boroughselect" >
  <option selected value=" ">Choose...</option>
//fill the options with the results of a query performed eariler - works
    <?php 
        for ($v=0; $v< sizeof($borough) ; $v++)
                {echo '"<option value="'.$bid[$v].','.$bboxa[$v].','.$bboxb[$v].','.$bboxc[$v].','.$bboxd[$v].'" >'.$borough[$v].'</option>';}
       ?>
 </select><br/>  
<input type="submit"  value="Go" name="postbor" class="formButton">
</form>



//the js
function goborough(g){

          var binfo=g.elements['boroughselect'].value;
          if(binfo!=" "){
                  //some cool openlayers staff here
          return false;
          }
          else{alert('You have not chosen a borough !!! ');return false;}

}
```

Comment: I think u have to add code for hitting enter button function...

Comment: 1) show rendered form (no php code) 2) check JS console

Comment: @ShumailMohy-ud-Din it will work fine like this for `input` elements, just not for `select`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your form element (the select) try this,

```
onkeypress="if(event.keyCode==13) {this.submit();}"
```

Or use jquery,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input").keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#broughtform").submit();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: It should be applied to the `select`, not the `form`.

Comment: Yes, I said form element that means the ``select``

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not in the code, but in that the `select` element has reserved the <kbd>enter</kbd> key for other purposes, see [why doesn't hitting enter when a SELECT is focused submit the form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968693/why-doesnt-hitting-enter-when-a-select-is-focused-submit-the-form)

Apply an `onkeypress` event to the `select` element to change this default behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure that everything is fine and it should go. Then you might use this:

```
onkeydown(submitform)
```

In the form tag, and in the function you should use this:

```
function submitform () {
  if(event.keyCode == 13) {
    // submit the form.. as enter key code is 13.
  }
}
```

I am not sure why its not working. You should try to read and look at the console from the browser, it must tell you what is the error. Try doing that by pressing F12 in your Browser. You will get an error code there, try Googling it, or sharing it in the Question.

Answer (score 0):

You should return `true` to submit the form but you are always returning false, `return false` and it prevents the submission.

**JS:**

```
function goborough(g){
    var binfo=g.elements['boroughselect'].value;
    if(binfo!=" "){
          //some cool openlayers staff here
          return true;
    }
    else{
        alert('You have not chosen a borough !!! ');
        return false;
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

You have this

```
onSubmit="return goborough(this); return false;"
```

but, it should be

```
onSubmit="return goborough(this);"
```

Comment: It's the whole point, he wants to submit to JS and not do an actual callback.